# How to send userdata from passportjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

Im authenticating with passportjs. I want to send the user, if authenticated, to Angular. So my code :

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info),{
        if(err) {
            return res.send({err: err, info:info});
        }
        res.send(user);
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to send the info to angular to log in to the console. I understand a session is created, but i just want to send (`res.send`) the info for debugging.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the custom callback authenticate method, so you need to handle the login yourself otherwise there will be no `user` object to send back to the client (AngularJS app).

Right from the [passport.js docs](http://passportjs.org/docs):

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

> In this example, note that `authenticate()` is called from within the
>   route handler, rather than being used as route middleware. This gives
>   the callback access to the `req` and `res objects` through closure.

Note: You'll have to send the user/error to the AngularJS client using the same method as in your code instead of re-directing like this example shows.

Comment: That worked. Now if I do another query to the db, will passport automatically know that im a legit user with whom the session is established? Tried `req["user"];` and `req.user` but getting undefined.

Comment: You will have to read up on the passport documentation some more. If my answer has answered your original question, could you upvote/select it as the chosen answer? :)